# Export to excel or CSV file with column and rows. List manipulation required

Tags: export, csv-format

```
ListA = {{{n1, p1, a1}, {n1, p2, a2}, {n1, p3, a3}, {n1 p4, a4}, {n1 p5,a5}, 
 {n1,p6, a6}},{{n2, p1, b1}, {n2, p2, b2}, {n2, p3, b3}, {n2, p4, b4}, 
 {n2, p5, b5}, {n2, p6, b6}}, {{n3, p1, c1}, {n3, p2, c2}, {n3, p3, c3}, 
 {n3, p4, c4}, {n3, p5, c5}, {n3,p6, c6}},.......etc...........
 {{n6, p1, f1}, {n6, p2, f2}, {n6, p3, f3}, {n6, p4, f4}, {n6, p5, f5}, 
 {n6, p6, f6}}}
```

I want to export ListA into CSV file so `n`s are the columns and the `p`s are the rows.   Then the values A-F at each cell at `n` column and `p` row. Something like `Export["MathematicaData.CSV", ListA /@ {1, 2, 3}]`, but this does not work as intended.

Here is an example set of numbers:

```
 {{{0.674, 0.573, -0.111}, {0.674, 0.912, -0.109}, {0.674, 
   1.251, -0.107}, {0.674, 1.59, -0.106}, {0.674, 
   1.93, -0.105}}, {{0.99, 0.573, -0.11}, {0.99, 
   0.912, -0.108}, {0.99, 1.251, -0.107}, {0.99, 1.59, -0.105}, {0.99,
    1.93, -0.104}}, {{1.307, 0.573, -0.109}, {1.307, 
   0.912, -0.108}, {1.307, 1.251, -0.106}, {1.307, 
   1.59, -0.105}, {1.307, 1.93, -0.103}}, {{1.623, 
   0.573, -0.109}, {1.623, 0.912, -0.107}, {1.623, 
   1.251, -0.106}, {1.623, 1.59, -0.104}, {1.623, 
   1.93, -0.103}}, {{1.939, 0.573, -0.108}, {1.939, 
   0.912, -0.107}, {1.939, 1.251, -0.105}, {1.939, 
   1.59, -0.104}, {1.939, 1.93, -0.103}}}
```

Comment: Oh yes forgot, I want to remove all curly brackets on export as well!

Comment: Can you give a small, numeric sample?

Comment: I've just updated with a set of number.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
ListA = {
  {{n1, p1, a1}, {n1, p2, a2}, {n1, p3, a3}, {n1, p4, a4}},
  {{n2, p1, b1}, {n2, p2, b2}, {n2, p3, b3}, {n2, p4, b4}},
  {{n3, p1, c1}, {n3, p2, c2}, {n3, p3, c3}, {n3, p4, c4}}};
Export["MathematicaData.CSV", Transpose[Map[Last, ListA, {2}]]]
```

gives this

```
a1,b1,c1,f1
a2,b2,c2,f2
a3,b3,c3,f3
a4,b4,c4,f4
```

in your csv file.

Note you are also missing some commas in your example, but I suspect those are just typos.

EDIT: Revised to include his requested row and column labels

```
collabels = Map[#[[1, 1]] &, ListA];
rowlabels = Join[{{0}}, Map[{#[[2]]} &, ListA[[1]]]];
Export["MathematicaData.CSV", 
  MapThread[Join, {rowlabels, 
    Join[{collabels}, Transpose[Map[Last, ListA, {2}]]]}, 1]]
```

which produces

```
0, n1,n2,n3
p1,a1,b1,c1
p2,a2,b2,c2
p3,a3,b3,c3
p4,a4,b4,c4
```

Comment: Thanks that works great.  But the first column needs to be the "n"s and the first row the "p"s.  Please can you update with this? Thanks

Comment: @SPIL. What goes in upper left corner then? A zero?

Comment: Yes a zero or blank is fine. Thanks

Comment: @SPIL labels added. From your original wording I would never have guessed you wanted labels. In the future you might consider posting something like: Given this input in this form I'd like to get output in this form. The example can't be too complicated, but it needs to be just complicated enough that whatever anyone answers will be certain to do all that you need.

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for your feedback. I'll take that on board for future posts.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
Export["filename.csv", ArrayFlatten[{{0, {list[[1, All, 2]]}}, {List /@ list[[All, 1, 1]], list[[All, All, 3]]}}]]
```

**OP**

I'm assuming all the `n`s and `p`s are integers. In that case, do

```
Export["filename.csv", SparseArray[{#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ Flatten[list, 1]]]
```

This works for the `n`s and `p`s in any order. If they are actually in the correct order, then [Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18890/bill)'s [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113873/29734) above is fine.

Note: I might have the columns and rows switched. In that case, change `{#1, #2}` in the code above to `{#2, #1}`.

Comment: No they are real numbers.  But thanks anyway, your method could be useful in the future.

Comment: @SPIL. Try the updated post. See if it works. You might need to put `Transpose@` in front of `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: That works!  Thanks for your efforts.